# Swift UISegmentedControl IBAction values do not change

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

So I am wanting to keep track of which direction the user would like to cycle through. Hence I have a segmented control to select the direction.

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var cycleSwitch: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func setCycleDirection(sender: AnyObject) {

        switch cycleSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex
            {
        case 0:
            cycleDirection = cycleSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex
        case 1:
            cycleDirection = cycleSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex
        default:
            break
        }
    println(cycleDirection)
}
```

but nothing gets printed. Even if I comment everything out and just have a println("Im in the action") does not log. I have also tried this as if statements e.g. cycleSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 etc. Neither works.

Any suggestions or thoughts as to why the values won't change?

Answer (score 5):

A few things to check:

1. Make sure your segmented control is hooked up to the `@IBAction` via its "Value Changed" action.
   To do this, control+click your segmented control in your Storyboard and double-check to make sure "Value Changed" is wired to your View Controller
2. Change the `sender:` argument to be a `UISegmentedControl` instead of `AnyObject`
3. Instead of referencing your `cycleSwitch` `@IBOutlet`, reference `sender` in your switch statement:

```
switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
                {
            case 0:
                cycleDirection = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
            case 1:
                cycleDirection = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
            default:
                break
            }
```

Comment: I have tried that also. Making the changes you suggest does not resolve the issue

Comment: And just to verify - you've confirmed that the `@IBAction` is connected to the "Value Changed" action for your segmented control and not something else?